# Cover letter salutation - Sir <Full Name>?

Tags: salutations

I know the hiring supervisor's name. Is it okay to open the cover letter with "Dear Sir *Full Name*"?

Comment: Does he have a knighthood?

Comment: Lol good question. I honestly don't know.

Comment: Wasn't "Sir Full Name" the overfed and squatty  younger child of Sir  First Name?

Comment: @Rattler I think you are thinking of "Sir Last Name" who famously died without children.

Comment: The hiring supervisor is unlikely to have a knighthood.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because letter salutations are a matter of style, not general English.

Comment: All you need is Dear Mr. Last Name, not Sir Last Name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**

"Sir Full Name" is only used when the person is a [knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight).

Use either "Dear Full Name" or "Dear Mr Lastname" (or "Dr Lastname etc."), or "Dear Sir" (without a name).

"Sir" only applies to men. "Madam" is the female equivalent, "Dear Sir/Madam" if you don't know which to use.